# Dualshock 4 deactivates automatically on PC

Tags: technical-issues, controllers

When I connect my DualShock 4 to the PC with Bluetooth, the light turns on and then turns off after a few seconds. In the Bluetooth settings it still shows as "Paired", but games and even DS4windows doesn't recognize it. Even when I connect it with a wire, I have to use DS4windows for all the buttons to work (even in games that natively support DS4). I never had these problems before so I'm guessing recent windows updates might have caused it (the controller shows up in the "other devices" part of the Bluetooth settings whereas before updates it showed up in the top section).

I'd really appreciate your help!

Comment: Have you already tried to uninstall the Dualshock drivers then install them again?

Comment: Have you tried downloading Steam and running the game through it? You will have to add the game to Steam library and configure your PS4 controller into steam controller settings. Here is how to add the game to steam library. https://support.steampowered.com/kb_article.php?ref=2219-YDJV-5557

Comment: @Zoma I don't know how to do that. is it even possible?

Comment: @IlJoker11 when I go steam controller settings (General controller settings) it says no controller detected! :(

Comment: @TlifeProgram Maybe try connecting the controller with USB cable before trying with Bluetooth

Comment: @TlifeProgram If you're using Windows, Options -> Devices (Bluetooth, printers, etc...) -> Search for Wireless Controller -> Delete ^^ Then as IIJoker11 said, try to link your controller with a cable first, then try to use Bluetooth again ^^